# ionic cards with ng-repeat with spaces between them

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to display a series of cards using ng-repeat. Something like.
[image]

What I am currently doing is

```
<ion-view view-title="Active">
```

```
  <div class ='child_div_1'>
    <div class="card cardS" collection-item-width="'20%'" collection-item-height="40%">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <p>dljfweiuf</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class ='child_div_2'>
    <div class="card" collection-repeat="item in items" collection-item-width="'25%'" collection-item-height="60%">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap "  id="cards">
        {{item}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am getting in my view is 
[image]
Can anyone help me with how to create gap between the cards the gap between two cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `padding` css property to the ng repeating div

```
<div class ='child_div_2'>
    <div class="card" collection-repeat="item in items" collection-item-width="'25%'" collection-item-height="60%" style="padding: 15px;">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap "  id="cards">
        {{item}}
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works the cards are coming up perfectly but there is a border in the background same like the above pic.

Comment: do you want to remove the border

Comment: yes just updated the 2nd image , its just the border around the cards that I am trying to remove

Comment: add this `border: none !important;`